# Как посчитать все возможные состояния 8 булевых переменных (комбинаций)

Tags: алгоритм, комбинаторика

Есть 8 булевых переменных, мне необходимо узнать все варианты сочетаний которые они могут принять. Например 1001 1001, 0100 1000 и т.д. Как я понимаю, таких комбинаций - 256, но не на бумаге же их предварительно считать.

Comment: Не понял. В заголовке написано "посчитать". В тексте написано "узнать". Так "посчитать" или "узнать"? И что вообще такое "узнать"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Первая может принять два значения.

Вторая - для каждого выбранного варианта первой - еще 2, итого - 2*2.

Для каждого из четырех вариантов третья может быть либо 0, либо 1 - еще 2, итого - 2*2*2.

Для N штук - 2<sup>N</sup>.

Правда, все просто? :)

Или - каждая булева - бит в N-битном числе. Разных чисел от 000...00 (N разрядов) до 111...11 - сколько? Понятно, что их 2<sup>N</sup>. Посмотрите сами - считаем от 1 до максимального значения - 111..11 (N единиц), + еще одно - нулевое - т.е. число, равное 1 и N нулей. Т.е. то же самое 2<sup>N</sup>...

И это и приводит нас к перечислению - просто цикл от 0 до 2<sup>N</sup>-1, а далее в битовом представлении каждый бит соответствует одной булевой переменной. Все их сочетания - это просто двоичное представление всех чисел от 0 до 2<sup>N</sup>-1.

На C++ (вы не указали язык) что-то типа

```
bool val[8];
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
{
    unsigned int n = i;
    for(int j = 0; j < 8; ++j)
    {
        val[j] = n%2;
        n >>= 1;
    }
    // Вот тут - массив val заполнен очередным набором
    // булевых значений
}
```

Или воспользуйтесь, например, готовым [`bitset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset).

Answer (score 1):

Количество всевозможных комбинаций равно `2` в степени `N`. В вашем случае - `2` в степени `8` равно `256`. Вот и весь подсчет. А у как вы будете возводить число в степень "не на бумаге" - зависит от вашего окружения и предоставляемых им средств.

Answer (score 0):

Как то так

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] values = new int[8];
    enumerate(values, 0);
}

private static void enumerate(int[] values, int index) {
    if (index >= values.length) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(values));
        return;
    }
    values[index] = 0;
    enumerate(values, index + 1);
    values[index] = 1;
    enumerate(values, index + 1);
}
```